# Google Sheets QUERY only takes 3 arguments, but this is argument number 4

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=IF(A2 = "", "", QUERY({
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$J$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$F$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$H$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$K$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$O$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$S$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$W$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1)
}, "select * where Col1 <> ''"))
```

`, "select * where Col1 <> ''"` is underlined red and shows the error: "QUERY only takes 3 arguments, but this is argument number 4."
When I remove the IF part it stops showing the error. Making it all be in one line doesn't help. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: It seems it may be a visual bug. The query processes correctly, but is still underlined red. The error stopped appearing after I ended up changing it to this:

```
=QUERY({
IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$J$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1), "");
IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$F$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1), "");
IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$H$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1), "");
IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$K$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1), "");
IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$O$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1), "");
IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$S$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1), "");
IFERROR(INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$W$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1), "")
}, "select * where Col1 <> ''")
```

Comment: Without seeing the data that you are working on its hard to tell. The size of the formula is also quite large. Why not use some intermediate ranges to make it easier for yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find any mistake

```
=IF(A2 = "", "", QUERY({
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$J$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$F$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$H$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$K$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$O$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$S$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1);
INDEX(Equipment!$C$2:$X, MATCH(A2, Equipment!$C$2:$C, 0), COLUMN(Equipment!$W$2) - COLUMN(Equipment!$C$2) + 1)
}, "select * where Col1 <> ''"))
```

[image]